# Every second sample noisy

Tags: noise, aliasing

I sampled a signal and unfortunately every second sample is **very** noisy.
The noise is Gaussian and bandlimited exactly in the same bandwidth as my signal.
Is there a way to improve the noise without averaging? I need to keep the original sample rate.

In theory I know the spectrum of my signal. I can skip all noisy (every second) samples and do a FFT. This gives me a spectrum with very low noise. But it is undersampled.

Comment: That's a peculiar setup. Do you know the phenomenon that is causing the noise to occur on such a schedule? Note that if the noise is only present in every other sample, and it covers the same bandwidth as your original signal, then it also is undersampled. Because of the [dual phenomenon to the one I refer to here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/33911/why-are-zero-values-added-in-the-fft-of-a-concatenated-noise-signal/33913#33913), the spectrum of the noise signal should actually be replicated twice in the frequency domain.

Comment: Can you describe the data source and signal processing that leads to this? Some detail might explain what you are doing.  I presume that the effect you mention is not intentional!   In addition, a link to some of the actual data might be helpful.